# django NoReverseMatch when trying to delete an object from database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm new to django and I've been stuck on a problem when trying to delete objects in my project's database.
I've made a function in my views.py that *should* delete objects that are passed to it. Problem is, my template doesn't seem to be passing information correctly to the url so the whole chain is breaking.

Here's the delete function in views.py

```
def delete_player(request, id):
    quarterback = Quarterback.get(id=id)
    quarterback.delete()

    return redirect('show')
```

The model "Quarterback" is here in models.py

```
class Quarterback(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

in my template called "show.html" I have this

```
<tr>  
        
    <td>{{ QB }}      
        <a href="{% url 'delete_player' quarterback.id %}">Delete</a>  
    </td> 
        
</tr>
```

Here's the path in urls.py

```
path('delete_player/<int:id>', views.delete_player, name="delete_player")
```

This all keeps returning a "NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_player' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['game/delete_player/(?P[0-9]+)$']"

The error message also keeps referring to my show() in views.py like this...

```
C:\Users\Leigh\Desktop\fantasyfootball\game\views.py, line 321, in show
        return render(request,"game/show.html", context)   …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
K   
'Greg Zuerlein K 10.0'
QB  
'Russell Wilson QB 41.34'
RB  
'Mark Ingram RB 31.5'
TE  
'Austin Hooper TE 18.6'
WR  
'Mike Evans WR 37.0'
context 
{'K': 'Greg Zuerlein K 10.0',
 'QB': 'Russell Wilson QB 41.34',
 'RB': 'Mark Ingram RB 31.5',
 'TE': 'Austin Hooper TE 18.6',
 'WR': 'Mike Evans WR 37.0'}
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/game/show'>
user    
<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>
```

Here is the full show() in views.py

```
def show(request): 

    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated: 

        try:
            QB = Quarterback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            QB = 'empty'

        try:
            RB = Runningback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            RB = 'empty'

        try:     
            WR = Widereceiver.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            WR = 'empty'

        try:
            TE = Tightend.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            TE = 'empty' 

        try:    
            K = Kicker.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            K = 'empty' 


        context = {
            'QB': QB[0:],
            'RB': RB[0:],
            'WR': WR[0:],
            'TE': TE[0:],
            'K': K[0:],
        }


        return render(request,"game/show.html", context)
```

I'm not sure how and why the show() function is relevant here and what I'd need to fix here.
It looks like there's no id being passed from the template, hence the url won't match. I'm totally at a loss at how to get the object's id passing correctly though. When I check the tables in the database using dbshell in the terminal, the tables are there with the prefix "game" (e.g. "game_quarterback") ( "game" is the name of my app). I can check what's inside the table and the player name is there. There's also an id column. How can I get the id to pass from the template in this case here? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The error seems to be in the `show` view, which you didn't reveal.

Comment: @KlausD.Yes, I sudden;y realized this and just added it.

Comment: Your context is missing a `quarterback`.

Comment: @KlausD.You're right. I changed the template to "{% url 'delete_player' QB.id %}" instead but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your view. `QB = Quarterback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]` is a String, actually name field's value of your Quaterback model. because `values_list` with `flat=True` returns `list`, and you access its first element. Than, later, when assembling the context you actually use substring `QB` variable. So, when accessing `QB` context variable in your template `{% url 'delete_player' QB.id %}` `QB` is actually a String, which of course does not have `id` param, which leads to an empty string, as it is invalid variable. See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled) for more. So, you need somehow to pass QB model instance to template, or actual `id` of it.

Comment: Thanks. That's really interesting and explains why there's no id param at all.